# Haproxy external check with arguments

Tags: haproxy, healthcheck

I'm trying to use the Option external-check and can't get it to work with an argument. It if I can't pass anything then that option becomes useless.

I've been trying for hours and nothing works. It only works with just the executable.

It gives me an error if I don't put quotes around the command but then it doesn't work at all. If I remove the IP then it works without the quotes.

here is an piece of code.

**This works**

```
.....
        bind *:15432
        option tcpka
        option external-check
        external-check path "/usr/bin:/bin"
        external-check command /bin/pg_check.py
.....
```

This does ***NOT*** work.

```
.....
        bind *:15432
        option tcpka
        option external-check
        external-check path "/usr/bin:/bin"
        external-check command /bin/pg_check.py 192.168.10.1
.....
```

This does ***NOT*** work

```
.....
        bind *:15432
        option tcpka
        option external-check
        external-check path "/usr/bin:/bin"
        external-check command "/bin/pg_check.py 192.168.10.1"
.....
```

How do I pass an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't explicitly configure arguments.  HAProxy adds them automatically.

> The arguments passed to the to the command are:
>
> The  and  are derived from the first listener
>   that is either IPv4, IPv6 or a UNIX socket. In the case of a UNIX socket
>   listener the proxy_address will be the path of the socket and the
>    will be the string "NOT_USED". In a backend section, it's not
>   possible to determine a listener, and both  and 
>   will have the string value "NOT_USED".
>
> Some values are also provided through environment variables.
>
> http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#4.2-external-check%20command

Comment: Yeah didn't quite catch that but decided to try another way. Thanks

Comment: Works for me with those variables, as described.